# Sitios web con background continuo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

queria informarme de como realizar una página con Bootstrap por ejemplo pero con un background continuo (Como los ejemplos que pongo abajo pero alargando el fondo como la página de docker: https://www.docker.com/).

Les agradeceria bastante su ayuda, un saludo.

Ej1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RF40SOl1JtE

Ej2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ca3ZkTV4RdM

Comment: ¿a que te refiereres con un backgroud continuo? Evita poner enlaces externos, esto podrian desaparecer en el futuro

Comment: Si ves el segundo ejemplo lo que me gustaria conseguir esque segun vayas bajando por la web esa linea que diferencia los dos colores continue. Entonces no sabría como hacerlo si luego hacer otro fondo donde intente ajustarlo como si la linea continuara o fuera un único fondo de un gran porcentaje de height. Espero que me hayas entendido ahora, disculpas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un `div` en tu `html` que contenga los objetos a los que vas a poner **background**

```
<div class="fondo">
     <!-- Código html -->
</div>
```

Luego, debes crear la imagen en formato SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics), guardarla en una carpeta de tu proyecto **(tu_proyecto/images/background.svg)** y luego invocarla desde `bootstrap.css` o de tu archivo `CSS` así:

```
.fondo {
    background: url(../images/background.svg) top no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```